# Why "toString" give different results corresponding to JFrame and System.out.println?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, tostring

When I have file with Russian letters they look fine as title of `JFrame`. But when I try to print them in the console it shows question icons. May somebody explain why it happens? And may be somebody have easier way to make title on Russian.

[image]

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    File file = new File("1.txt");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    try (InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
        int a = reader.read();
        while(a!=-1){
            result.append((char)a);
            a = reader.read();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(result.toString());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);

    System.out.println(result.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: I think console only supports non-special characters. That's probably why.

Comment: The problem is that the console uses a font that does not support those characters. The console is not relevant to the user of the application, so I don't see how this is important.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with your code, but rather a "problem" with the console. The console doesn't know what your Russian characters mean, so it prints the question marks. JFrame, on the other hand, knows Russian symbols, and is able to print them.

Comment: thank you for help. But maybe you also know easier way to put russian letters in Frame? I fill my self bad useing such method